# Ansible copy files and getting sources and destinations names of file from two lists

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts, ansible-template

i have to copy and rename multiple files

I ve the list of sources files names and destinations files names stored in two lists :

Here the **sources_files** list :

```
sources_files:
 - /path1/sourceFileOne.txt
 - /path2/sourceFileTwo.txt
 ...
 - /pathN/fileN.txt
```

Here the **destination_files** list :

```
destination_files:
 - /path1/destFileOne.txt
 - /path2/destFileTwo.txt
 ...
 - /pathN/destfileN.txt
```

Now i want that my Copy task do the copy from the **source** file to the **destination** file

`/path1/destFileOne.txt` **->**   `/path1/sourceFileOne.txt`

I ve tried looping with "**with_nested**"

```
- name: Rename or copy sources files to new names and paths
  copy:
   remote_src: True
   src: "{{ item[0] }}"
   dest: "{{ item[1] }}"
  when:
    - ansible_host in groups[SERVER]
  with_nested:
    - "{{sources_files}}"
    - "{{destination_files}}"
```

But that seems to notwork properly since that copy finally alway the content of last dest file

**Suggestions ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you've structured your data you probably want `with_together` or the `zip` filter.

```
- name: Rename or copy sources files to new names and paths
  copy:
   remote_src: True
   src: "{{ item[0] }}"
   dest: "{{ item[1] }}"
  when:
    - ansible_host in groups[SERVER]
  loop: "{{ sources_files|zip(destination_files) }}"
```

Having said that, I wonder if rather than maintaining two separate
lists it makes more sense to combine them, e.g.:

```
copy_files:
  - src: /src/file1
    dst: /dst/file1
  - src: /src/file2
    dst: /dst/file2
```

That makes it less likely your two lists end up out of sync.

Given that data structure, your task would look like:

```
- name: Rename or copy sources files to new names and paths
  copy:
   remote_src: True
   src: "{{ item.src }}"
   dest: "{{ item.dst }}"
  when:
    - ansible_host in groups[SERVER]
  loop: "{{ copy_files }}"
```

Comment: i don't know the numero of files , it s dynamic , so that i cannot formalize them like you did with (compy_files object" it's passed within variables ... but that works fine with with_together